# App crash with error - java.lang.AbstractMethodError after upgrading to gms:play-services 11

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play-services

My Google signin was working then i had to upgrade the google play services auth library from 10. to 11.2.0 then it started giving me this error when i run the app

```
  java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zze com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zza.zza(android.content.Context, android.os.Looper, com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzq, java.lang.Object, com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks, com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$OnConnectionFailedListener)"
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.dishesteam.dishes.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:138)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

I moved the library back down to 11.0.4 but it still crashes. I did not find much information on this error with google play auth but it seems its quiet common while using react and android native.

The line of code that the error specifies is -

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
            .build();
```

My build.gradle file looks like this -

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.0'
}
 }
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
  }
}
android {

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dishesteam.dishes"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    multiDexEnabled true
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.1.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.4@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev183-1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile files('libs/PhotoUtil.jar')
compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.2.0'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.8'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same configuration 11.0.4 and it is working fine. Here is my Code:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }/* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```

and later calling the following function

```
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

and the `startActivityForResult` is

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
                progress.setMessage("Connecting Please Wait!..");
                progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                progress.setIndeterminate(true);
                progress.show();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure whats wrong with my config.....what google play libraries are you using?

Comment: These are the libraries:
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'

Answer (score 0):

This information might be of help. There's been some changes in Google Play Services version 11.2.0. Your app's compileSdkVersion must be at least 26.

You can read more of that here [Some Updates to Apps Using Google Play services](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/08/some-updates-to-apps-using-google-play.html).

Looking at your `compileSdkVersion` it's set to 25. Try changing that to 26.

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to clean and build my project and it worked...I didnt change anything...thanks to Sahil and Noogui for their answers all the same.